# Автоперенос элементов на следующую строку в Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Мне необходимо расположить много кнопок подряд (горизонтально). Для всех кнопок ширина задана как `wrap_content`. Располагаю я их в `LinearLayout` (горизонатльный). Проблема в том, что если суммарная ширина всех кнопок превышает ширину экрана устройства, то кнопки не переносятся автоматически на слeдующую строку, а сплющиваются в тоненькую полоску в конце экрана.

Вопрос: как сделать автоперенос кнопок?

Answer (score 1):

Задайте в `LinearLayout` суммарный вес `android:weightSum="100"` и для каждой кнопке укажите сколько она процентов может занимать на экране с помощью параметра  `android:layout_weight="20"`. Для второго ряда вам придется создать еще один `LinearLayout` автоматом переносить не будет. Для этих целей нужно использовать `RelativeLayout` он задает относительное положение от какого-нибудь элемента. Посмотрите в сторону `RelativeLayout` он удобнее и более динамичный чем `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Занеси все кнопки в `<TabLayout></TabLayout>` или в `<TableRow></TableRow>`.